# How to make sidebar scroll Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, scroll

Today i learn about CSS Bootstrap 4 and i create my template with sidebar, but when many menu, i want sidebar show the scrollbar.

how to make scrollbar on my sidebar template, this is my HTML and my CSS code, please help me for this my issue. i will make sidebar with scroll and fixed

thanks very much

```
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 10</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 11</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 12</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 13</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 14</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[preview template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqae.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by simply adding Bootstrap classes...

```
    <div class="bg-light border-right min-vh-100" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush overflow-auto vh-100">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 1</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 3</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 4</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 5</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 6</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 7</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 8</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 9</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 10</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 11</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 12</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 13</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 14</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/VVByb17KWb

Comment: i get problem with content very height bro, i screenshot on this link : https://i.imgur.com/4KtwRoU.png

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the code of `#sidebar-wrapper`. It will add a scrollbar when `overflow-y happens`. I hope I understand your problem well.

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 100vh; /* Add height */
  overflow-y: auto;  /* Add overflow-y */
  overflow-x: hidden;  /* Add overflow-x */
  /* min-height: 100vh; */
  margin-left: -15rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
  transition: margin .25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    #sidebar-wrapper {
      height: 100vh;
      /* Add height */
      overflow-y: auto;
      /* Add overflow-y */
      overflow-x: hidden;
      /* Add overflow-x */
      /* min-height: 100vh; */
      margin-left: -15rem;
      -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
      -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
      -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
      transition: margin .25s ease-out;
    }
    
    #sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
      padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
    
    #sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
      width: 15rem;
    }
    
    #page-content-wrapper {
      min-width: 100vw;
    }
    
    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      #page-content-wrapper {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: -15rem;
      }
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap </div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 10</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 11</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 12</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 13</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Menu 14</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
        <p>The starting state of the menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will change.</p>
        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>. The top navbar is optional, and just for demonstration. Just create an element with the <code>#menu-toggle</code> ID which will toggle the menu when clicked.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- /#wrapper -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how to make scroll bar on list group only ? without sidebar heading

Answer (score 1):

I only added `overflow-auto` to my div class and worked well on Bootstrap 5